# How to use Bootstrap tooltip in Angularjs ng-repeat for div

Tags: angularjs

```
<div data-ng-repeat="provider in providers">
<div>
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
data-original-title="Default tooltip"/>&nbsp;
<b>Add to compare</b>
</div>
</div>
```

If using this code under ng-repeat it is not working.If im using without ng-repeat it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `attribute` used for `Bootstrap Tooltip Title` is "`title`" and not "`data-original-title`"

You can use

**Html**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="provider in providers">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Provider {{provider}}" />
        <b>Add to compare</b>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // Check/uncheck all boxes
  $scope.providers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


});
```

Refer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bzbDSf5bGpT0EMCD9qw1?p=preview)

Refer [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)